# Unable to exit TUIs due to F10 opening the File pull-down menu instead of quitting the program as meant to

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, tui

I use applications such as `Midnight Commander`, and `htop`, however I have a problem when quitting, I am forced to either terminate the process, or to click on the quit button myself, if there is one, because in a lot of TUIs there is not. The problem is is there most of them say to press <kbd>F10</kbd> to quit, however when pressing that, I just get it opening up the `File` pull-down menu:

[image]

So I am unable to quit using the keyboard. I am using `gnome-terminal`, I have tested this in `xfce4-terminal`, and the problem is there too. So why is this happening? And is there any fix for this so that it does not launch this pull-down menu and instead does what it's meant to and quit?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: Gnome
Gnome Version: 3.16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Three ways to modify the <kbd>F10</kbd> behaviour

**1. Via terminal preferences**

1. Open your `gnome-terminal` and the <kbd>Preferences</kbd>
2. Disable the entry <kbd>Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default)</kbd>

   [image]

---

**2. Via command line**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings menu-accelerator-enabled false
```

---

**3. Via `dconf-editor`**

1. Open the `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`)
2. Navigate to `org.gnome.terminal.legacy`
3. Deselect the entry `menu-accelerator-enabled` in the right pane

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on `gnome-terminal` window and uncheck "Show Menu" , and it will allow using <kbd>F10</kbd> key.

You can use alternative method for exiting programs,too. For `htop` you can use <kbd>Q</kbd> key to exit. For `Midnight Commander` or `mc` you can use the built-in command line to type `exit` there.

Alternatively, you can switch to another terminal that doesn't rely on F keys for showing the menu for the terminal. For instance, `xterm` or `sakura`. I've used the last one as alternative to `gnome-terminal` many times.

Comment: Is there any way though to just get `gnome-terminal` to not respond to the `F10` key? Is there no configuration for this?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda well, if you right click on the terminal and chose not to show the Menu, then it works.

Comment: Could you please include that as an option in your answer. :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda done and done :)